# ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row - Mysql Update without select

Tags: mysql

I don't understand what's happening.

here's my query

```
UPDATE rad 
SET `IDType` = '1', `XB` = '1096513935', `Name` = 'R2', `Identifier` = '3', `IDGPS` = '3', `IDSect` = '5', `Initial` = '0', `IDModif` = '99', `DateModif` = NOW() 
WHERE  IDRad = '3'
```

i get this message :

> ```
> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
> ```

Here's the result if I do a select for my `IDRad`

```
select * from rad where IDRad = 3;

+-------+--------+--------+-------+------+------------+------------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| IDRad | IDSect | IDType | IDGPS | Name | Identifier | XB         | Initial | IDUserModif | DateModif           |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+------+------------+------------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|     3 |      1 |      1 |     3 | R2   | 3          | 1096513935 |       0 |          99 | 2018-01-19 01:14:01 |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+------+------------+------------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, I don't do a select, so how can a subquery can be return? And, anyway, when I do a select with this ID, I only get one row...

Comment: WHERE  IDRad = '3' is not a subquery. Sounds like the error is for a different query.

Comment: Are you sure it is this sql query which cause problemes? Because I don't see any subquery in the update statement.

Comment: Yes. This is the exact query i run in the command line...

Comment: Do you have any UPDATE triggers on this table?

Comment: Yes!!! I didn't remember that but it's probably that! Thanks!!!